# How to change the range slider addition by click on radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have two radio buttons and multiple range sliders. Both radio buttons have different values. 
What I want is when I click on one of the radio buttons, the max value should be change(12 changed to 24, 24 changed to 12). And the addition of those range sliders moves up to the radio button's value.

```html
<input type="radio" id="starter" name="plan" value="starter">
<label for="starter">Up to 12</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="plus" name="plan" value="plus">
<label for="plus">Up to 24</label><br>

 <input type="range" id="range-1" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
 <input type="range" id="range-1" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
 <input type="range" id="range-1" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
 <input type="range" id="range-1" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `addition of those range sliders moves up to the radio button's value..` ? Also , are you using [this](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) plugin ?

Comment: It means one slider moves to 6, the second moves to 4, and the third moves to 2, but the fourth one can't be move. Because those 3  sliders reach up to 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your range slide change you can calculate **total** of all sliders using `.each` loop and check if the total is greater then max value if yes you can set the last slider value which is change to `0`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".slider").on("change", function() {
console.clear()
  var max = $("[name=plan]:checked").data('max')
  var total = 0
  //get total
  $(".slider").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val()) //calculate total
  })
  console.log("Total --" + total + " Max --" + max)
  if (total > max) {
    $(this).val(0) //set value to 0 again..
    console.log("can't move..")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added max-->
<input type="radio" id="starter" name="plan" data-max="12" value="starter" checked>
<label for="starter">Up to 12</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="plus" name="plan" data-max="24" value="plus">
<label for="plus">Up to 24</label><br>

<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1" class="slider range-slider"><br>
```

Comment: This is the correct code but how do I add numbers on the blue circle of the slider, so I get to know how many number sliders move.

Comment: Try like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3kL7jfz2/1/) let me know if you resolve that or not and if you need to do that in css i m not good in that :) you can ask new question for that .

Comment: Thank you again for solving most of my JS-related questions. How do you know JS so well?

Comment: :P Learning here by giving answers .